# Buttons width in table layout

Tags: android

i am learning TableLayout in android and in the following layout some discrepancy in result is coming.
i am having 3 Buttons infirst row and 2 Buttons in second row .
the following is the code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this Button is big"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

When the middle button text is larger ,the two buttons are not coming equal inspite of their weight being equal.
However when the text of the last button is increased the buttons come equal.
kindly update why the buttons are not coming equal when middle text is bigger
attached are the two images
[image]
[image]
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting layout_width of each button to match_parent, while keeping weight = 1. match_parent will tell the buttons to consume as much space as possible, while weight determines how that space will be distributed. You should also specify how you want the button text to be truncated, i.e. single line, ellipsize, etc.

Comment: it is not required to specify width for children of tablelayout.kindly go through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html